# magento 2 How to store Customer Address custom attribute value quote_address table column

Tags: magento2, quote, customer-address-attribute

I have created customer address type custom attribute and it's value store as custom attribute now I want to store this value on quote address column.

I have create observer sales_quote_address_save_before type and then do the coding as per below way.

```
  <?php
    namespace Vendor\Extension\Observer;
    
    use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    
    class QuoteAddressBeforeSave implements ObserverInterface
    {
        public function execute(Observer $observer)
        {
            $dataObject = $observer->getEvent()->getDataObject();
            $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $cusaddress = $om->get('Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface');
        $addressId = 15;
        $addressData = $cusaddress->getById($addressId);
        $addressidnew = $dataObject->getData('address_id');
        }
    }
?>
```

So here, I pass static customer id and get custom attribute value it's working. so now I want to store this custom attribute value on quote address table column.

How to get customer address id dynamic base on selection of address on checkout page and store value on quote address.

Comment: Are you getting  selected ```address id` at event `sales_quote_address_save_before ` using  `$observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_address')->getData('customer_address_id')`

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a field at `quote_address` using `db_scheme.xml` at your module `app/code/{Vendorname}/{Module}/etc` .Assume that your field name is **my_field** .
This field will save the value for your attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="quote_address">
        <column name="my_field" nullable="true" xsi:type="varchar" comment="my_field" length="255"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

You can get your selected Customer address ID at `sales_quote_address_save_before`  observer using below code:

```
$object = $observer->getEvent()->getDataObject();
$addressId = $object->getCustomerAddressId();
```

**Observer code:**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Observer;

use Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class QuoteAddressBeforeSave implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var AddressRepositoryInterface
     */
    private  $addressRepository;

    public function __construct(AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository)
    {

        $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;
    }
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $object = $observer->getEvent()->getDataObject();
        $addressId = $object->getCustomerAddressId();
        $newField = 'customer_new_field';
        if (!empty($addressId) && (int) $addressId > 0){
            try {
                $customerAddress = $this->addressRepository->getById((int)$addressId);
                if (null !== $customerAddress->getCustomAttribute($newField)){
                    $object->setData('my_field',$customerAddress->getCustomAttribute($newField)->getValue());
                }

            } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            }
        }

    }
}
```